# alpha test shader 'discard' operation not working - GLES2

Tags: opengl, android, shaders, opengl-es2, fragment-shader

I wrote this `shader` to illustare `alpha test` action in `GLES2` (Galaxy S6).
I think is not working at all cause I don't see any change with or without it.
Is there anything Im missing?
Any syntax error?
**I know its better not using `if` in `shader` but for now this is the solution I need.**

```
precision highp float;
precision highp int;
precision lowp sampler2D;
precision lowp samplerCube;

        //0 - CMPF_ALWAYS_FAIL,
        //1 - CMPF_ALWAYS_PASS,
        //2 - CMPF_LESS,
        //3 - CMPF_LESS_EQUAL,
        //4 - CMPF_EQUAL,
        //5 - CMPF_NOT_EQUAL,
        //6 - CMPF_GREATER_EQUAL,
        //7 - CMPF_GREATER

        bool Is_Alpha_Pass(int func,float alphaRef, float alphaValue)
        {
            bool result = true;
            if (func==0)
            {
                result = false;
                break;
            }

            if (func==1)
            {
                result = true;
                break;
            }
            if (func==2)
            {
                result = alphaValue < alphaRef;
                break;
            }
            if (func==3)
            {
                result = alphaValue <= alphaRef;
                break;
            }
            if (func==4)
            {
                result = alphaValue == alphaRef;
                break;
            }
            if (func==5)
            {
                result = alphaValue != alphaRef;
                break;
            }
            if (func==6)
            {
                result = alphaValue >= alphaRef;
                break;
            }
            if (func==7)
            {
                result = alphaValue > alphaRef;
                break;
            }
            return result;
        }


void FFP_Alpha_Test(in float func, in float alphaRef, in vec4 texel)
{
    if (!Is_Alpha_Pass(int(func), alphaRef, texel.a))
        discard;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glBlendFunc.xhtml

Did you check the glblendfunc??

It is needed to be enabled in client state with gl_alpha_test

Without client state code it's difficult for me to solve the problem.